# "type mismatch" implementing typed Security.authenticated

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to implement a common authentication trait for a non-String version of Security.authenticated. I want return an instance of a Person if the authentication is successful, rather than the default String (e.g. username). Code is something like this so far:

```
trait Secured {
  def withPerson[Person](f: => Person => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {

    def findPerson(request:RequestHeader) : Option[Person] =
      Person.findByRuid("me")
    def noPerson(request:RequestHeader) = Results.BadRequest("No access")

    Security.Authenticated[Person](findPerson, noPerson) { person =>
      Action { implicit request => 
        f(person)(request)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Person.findByRuid` is defined in the models package to return an `Option[Person]`, so I thought this would be simple, but am hitting some sort of type parameter/type path issue, and receive the following compile-time error message on the line calling my model method:

```
type mismatch; 
  found : Option[models.Person] 
  required: Option[Person]
```

I seem to have missed something in my Scala type education and would appreciate help. How do I associate my models.Person with the Person type parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue just remote the type parameter in withPerson

```
def withPerson(f: => Person => Request[AnyContent] => Result)
```

As you can see there is no need for that, Person is already defined.

If you want to define a generic Secure trait you could do something like

```
trait Secured[A] {

  def validate(request:RequestHeader) : Option[A]

  def secure(f: => A => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {

    def notAllowed(request:RequestHeader) = Results.BadRequest("No access")

    Security.Authenticated[A](validate, notAllowed) { a =>
      Action { implicit request =>
        f(a)(request)
      }
    }
  }
}

trait SecuredWithPerson extends Secured[Person] {
  def validate(request:RequestHeader) : Option[Person] =
    Person.findByRuid("me")
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Somehow, looking at the signature I had fixated on putting the type parameter in.